# How to set custom value of object to textfield tag in Struts2

Tags: struts2, textfield

I want to use the value of custom object in textfield. 
Is it done by EL expression or any other way?
Scriplets does not work as mentioned below

```
<s:textfield label="Login" name="loginName" value=<%=temp.getLoginName()%>/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a getter for the custom object from your action and a getter for its 'value' and then do:

```
<s:textfield value="%{customObject.value}"/>
```

Comment: that my custom object is from just a class which has getter setter methods. But not action class.                                      int faqId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
Faq temp = new Faq().fetch(faqId);

Comment: This sentence makes no sense; as suggested, you must declare the instance variable of your custom object (a POJO, or standard class) INSIDE your Action, as private, then expose it through an Accessor, (or Getter). Then this solution will work. This is standard Struts2, avoid scriptlet and dark solutions to prevent obscure problems...

Comment: @AndreaLigios This jsp page is not forwarded from action class. It is from another JSP. In that case what I could use to achieve this?

Comment: That is the problem: do not forward JSPs to JSPs... use Action to JSP, or Action to Action... btw you can achieve that putting variables in Session, but I strongly suggest you to redesign that part of your web application

Comment: @AndreaLigios thank you. Can i ask you one more thing? Are there any way to display field error from validate method on normal html form tag?

Comment: U mean with scriptlet ? Dunno, I've never had this kind of problem, the `<fielderrors/>` tag do that for you in a second: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/FieldError.html . Believe me, once you'll use the framework as it is intended, you will have no strange problems anymore, and will do more, better things in less time. Give it a try :)